# Stripping Specific Information with Bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep, grafana, influxdb

I have a small bash script that looks at the chassis temps on a Dell server.  The script will be running against 50 servers from Icinga2 and report the findings into Granfana via Influxdb. I need to grab the temps from the following output:

```
Temperature Probes Information

--
Probe Name                : System Board Inlet Temp
Reading                   : 21.0 C
--
Probe Name                : CPU1 Temp
Reading                   : 39.0 C
```

I was thinking of using awk to just print the values (echo the variable without quotes, awk '{print $14}' would give me 21.0 as an example.

The issue is that I have a few servers with 2 CPUS and the awk position will differ

The code I have thus far to gather the above output is:

```sh
HOST=$1

dell_probes=$(ssh someUser@${HOST} "/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/omreport chassis temps | grep Probe -A1")

echo "$dell_probes"
```

I've not tried any sed/awk solutions yet, just not sure what the most elegant approach to this would be.

I'd like the output to look like the following so I can use it with influxdb:

```sh
echo "$mb_temp"
21.0

echo "$cpu1_temp"
39.0

echo "$anyother_cpu_listed"
39.1
```

Comment: This may be a step in the right direction: `| awk -F ' : | C' '/Probe Name/{name=$2} /Reading/{print name,$2}'`

Comment: This is okay, thank you.  How could I use the above to assign to the output to separate variables?  When I echo the vars, it shows as `System Board Inlet Temp 23.0, CPU1 Temp 39.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array. I'd load it with `sed`.

```
$: temps=( $(  sed -nE '
     /^Reading / {
       s/^Reading *: *([0-9.]+).*/\1/;
       p; 
     }
   ' input ) )
$: for t in "${!temps[@]}"
> do echo "Temp for CPU $t - > ${temps[$t]}"
> done
Temp for CPU 0 - > 21.0
Temp for CPU 1 - > 39.0
```

Comment: So for every item in the array, it would just loop through?  Any way to assign to variables?  For example, the MB is a separate value than CPU1, these need to be vars. Need to be able to use this output within Grafana.  Thanks for the reply too, appreciated.

Comment: `${!temps[@]}"` (note the `!`) returns the *indexes* of `${temps[@]}"` to `$t`, which it loops over....Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You never need grep when you're using awk. This is probably what you need:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

declare -A temps="( $(
    #/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin/omreport chassis temps |
    cat file |
    awk -F'[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*' '
        f { sub(/ .*/,"",$NF); printf "[%s]=\"%s\"\n", name, $NF; f=0 }
        $1 == "Probe Name" { name=$2; sub(/ Temp$/,"",name);  gsub(/ /,"_",name); f=1 }
    '
) )"

printf '%s\n' "${temps[System_Board_Inlet]}"

printf '%s\n' "${temps[CPU1]}"

$ ./tst.sh
21.0
39.0
```

I used `cat file` instead of your real command which I commented out since that's all I have to use as input for now.